# OO PHP Constructor is not working?

Tags: php, oop, object, constructor

I'm new to developing objectoriented PHP and trying to create a login-system. Therefore, I made an index file and two classes. It seems to me, that, using var_dump(), the output would contain the elements status, username and more.

But what happens is that i get this notice:

```
notice: Undefined variable: connector in C:\xampp\htdocs\1-4-LT3\Concept\Authenticator.php on line 15

Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\1-4-LT3\Concept\Authenticator.php on line 15
```

To me, it seems that the constructors aren't working.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the  $connector variable undefined?

Oh and I am aware that this way is very unsafe, but I'm just trying to make some sense of OO PHP.

The index.php file:

```
<?php
include 'Connector.php';
include 'Authenticator.php';
$connector = new Connector('localhost', 'root', '', 'hondsrug_db');
$authenticator = new Authenticator($connector);

$authenticator->login('root', 'admin');
var_dump($authenticator);
?>
```

The connector.php file:

```
<?php
class Connector {
    var $mysqli;
    var $host;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    public function Connector($host, $username, $password, $database){
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function query($query){
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            return $result->fetch_assoc;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public function connect(){
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
    }
    public function disconnect(){
        $mysqli->close();
    }

}


?>
```

and the Authenticator.php file:

```
<?php
// maakt verbinding met db
// logt in adh van methode
// bepaalt rang, en implementeert hiervoor een getter
class Authenticator {
    var $connector;
    var $status;
    var $username;
    var $rank;
    public function Authenticator($connector){
        $this->connector = $connector;
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        $connector->connect();
        $result = $connector->query('SELECT password, rank FROM users WHERE username = '.$username);
        if($result != null){
            if($result['password'] == SHA1($password)){
                $this->status = true;
                $this->username = $username;
                $this->rank = $result['rank'];
            } else {
                $this->status = false;
                $this->username = null;
                $this->rank = null;
            }
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }

        $connector->disconnect();
    }

    public function getRank(){
        return $rank;
    }

    public function getStatus(){
        return $status;
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: Just a small note which may affect you some day. If you start using namespaces and the last element of a namespace has the same name as a method, this method will not get treated as constructor. So I would recommend to use __construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here

```
$connector->connect();
```

You have used the var $connector inside the class Authenticator and inside the constructor you have

```
 $this->connector = $connector;
```

so while accessing the method you will need to do as

```
 $this->connector->connect();
```

Now you are using class name as a function name to make it as constructor, it works though as a backward compatibility , but its better to use magic method `__construct` and also instead of `var` you may start using `public,private, protected`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $this explicitly in PHP. ALWAYS sadly.

```
public function login($username, $password){
    $this-> connector->connect();
```

Comment: Why sadly? Would you prefer the language to just guess what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Your login method needs to use

```
$this->connector->connect();
$result = $this->connector->query('SELECT password, rank FROM users WHERE username = '.$username);
```

and

```
$this->connector->disconnect();
```

not

```
$connector->connect();
$result = $connector->query('SELECT password, rank FROM users WHERE username = '.$username);
```

or

```
$connector->disconnect();
```